# How to change date Culture of a dateTime in DataTable or from GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have a some fields in database and two of them are as DateTime Field, which I am retrieving it via 'DataTable' in the GridView as in below code

**C# Code**

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(_TestMySqlConString);
string query1 = myQuery;
var cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query1, connection);
connection.Open();
var dataTable1 = new DataTable();
var da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
da1.Fill(dataTable1);
grdInvitationTendersList.DataSource = dataTable1;
grdInvitationTendersList.DataBind();
```

**ASP Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdList" runat="server"
                AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="R_NUMBER" OnRowCommand="grdList_RowCommand" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
 <Columns>
....
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="TENDER_NUMBER" HeaderText="T_NUMBER" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="T_NUMBER"  Visible="TRUE"></asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_DATE_SUBMISSION" HeaderText="Last Date of Submission" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LAST_DATE_SUBMISSION" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-BackColor="pink" FooterStyle-BorderColor="White" Visible="True" DataFormatString="{0:g}"></asp:BoundField>
......
 </Columns>
```

`LAST_DATE_SUBMISSION` is a `dateTime` Field.

My question is that How can I have the DateTime in `yyyy/MM//dd hh:mm:ss`, I have to convert the `culture` and display the DateTime in the GridView

**EDIT 1: ** `I admit that my question is not cleared. Let me explain more, My second part of question is that "I have to convert the Datetime to other Calender type and then display in the GridView"`

Comment: Are you asking about how to set the DateTime format pattern independently of current culture?

Comment: I am asking that I have a Gregorian date in Database (Getting via datatable) and want to convert in other calendar type and then display in GridView.

Comment: See the edit to my answer - a DateTime is always effectively Gregorian, but if you use a culture with a different calendar system it will be converted automatically.

Answer (score 3):

A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a culture, inherently. It's just a value. I suspect that you should change this though:

```
DataFormatString="{0:g}"
```

For example, change it to:

```
DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}"
```

(Note the `HH` rather than `hh`, assuming you actually want a 24-hour view. Likewise I assume the `//` in your question was a typo.)

That's if you want to hard-code it to the particular format. If you actually want "whatever the appropriate format is for the culture" then you should make sure the current culture is correct while you're processing the request, and your original `DataFormatString` is appropriate.

EDIT: I've now seen your about wanting to change calendar system as well - in that case it really *is* about making sure you're using the right culture. A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a calendar system; the calendar system is determined by the culture it's displayed in.

An alternative would be to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library - convert the value into a `LocalDateTime` with whatever calendar you want, which can be displayed independently of culture.

Comment: is giving the same answer I'll provide (sure his answer is billion times better than  mine) if you check this link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx you'll find format specifier "d" will change the date format according to the Thread Culture.

Comment: @EmadMokhtar Should I use `<asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_DATE_SUBMISSION" HeaderText="Last Date of Submission" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LAST_DATE_SUBMISSION" Visible="True" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundField>` and use the culture on ASP page what I need?

Comment: @AbdulAziz: Well that only gives the date - are you looking for a date, or looking for a date and time?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I know if i use `{0:g}` i can get something like this (6/15/2009 1:45 PM) but when I am using the culture as `Culture="ar-SA"` it says that `"Specified time is not supported in this calendar"`

Comment: @AbdulAziz: That suggests you're not managing to pull the date and time properly. It works fine for me - `new DateTime(2009, 6, 15, 13, 35, 0).ToString("g", new CultureInfo("ar-SA"))` gives "22/06/30 01:45" followed by a month name which doesn't show properly on my console.

Comment: @AbdulAziz I mentioned "d" as example, and I've tried your scenario and It's working with me without errors. Output: 22/06/30 01:45 م

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks to point the mistake. Can you suggest some solution?

Comment: @AbdulAziz: Not really, as we don't know where you're getting the date from.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting dateTime form mySQL database's DateTime Field

Comment: @AbdulAziz: *As* a `DateTime`? Or are you parsing it as a string for some reason, and then trying to reformat?

Comment: @JonSkeet As in my Original question, you can see in C# code that I am getting all fields by query and

Comment: @AbdulAziz: Hmm. Then I really don't understand why it would cause a problem. So you see "6/15/2009 1:45 PM" when viewing it in a US culture?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I can see "6/15/2009 1:45 PM" when viewing it in a US culture

Comment: @AbdulAziz: In that case I'm really surprised. Is it definitely *that date* which is causing the problem in ar-SA? If you've got `DateTime.MinValue` anywhere, for example, *that* would cause the problem when converting to ar-SA. I think you'll need to work on pinpointing which date causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `DataFormatString` to `{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}`

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_DATE_SUBMISSION" HeaderText="Last Date of Submission" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LAST_DATE_SUBMISSION" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-BackColor="pink" FooterStyle-BorderColor="White" Visible="True" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}" </asp:BoundField>
```

I hope this will work for you